# In XSL-FO, have cell content fill from the bottom up

Tags: xslt, cell, xsl-fo

I have a 2x1 table, and I was wondering how to have the content of one of the cells fill from the bottom up.

Creating a block-container with attribute **position="bottom"** didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display-align="after"` to your `fo:table-cell`.

```
<fo:table-cell display-align="after">
  <fo:block>...</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Cool that worked.  Here's another question:  Let's say there are 2 blocks inside the table-cell and you want 1 of them near the top, and the 2nd one would be floating to the bottom.  What would you do?

Comment: I added another table inside the div and applied display-align to it which worked.